# Android AlertDialog how to pass args

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, args

I have the activity A (which have the Custom Adapter for Listview), in the code of the 'Custom Adapter', I want to call the AlertDialog which will display me the second activity (activity B).

I can show perfectly the activity, but I would like to know how to pass args between activity A and activity B?

CustomAdapter.java:

```
view_details.setClickable(true);
view_details.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_activity_B, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
        AlertDialog alertD = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertD.show();
```

Firstly, I thought only about to put the following code beneath the 'alertD.show()':

```
TextView title_ = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_B); // Activity B
title_.setText("Example");
```

But didn't work. Then I thought about pass args between activities, using 'Bundle'. So, again, after the 'alertD.show()':

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, activityB.class);
i.putExtra("title", "this is the title"));
// And get this way in ActivityB:
// Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
// String g = extras.getString("title");
```

Also didn't work.
With this last code I receive no errors, but it doesn't display info also. With the "setText" I receive a error of a NullPointerException (it's like, the activity wasn't initialize then it retrieves error.)

Thanks.

Comment: question is not clear and also post logcat

Comment: in i.putExtra("title", "this is the title")); you write two closing brackets. maybe the reason you not receiving anything.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

My point with AlertDialog was to have that kind of window. I found that we can set that type of window(dialog) into our theme. Therefore, everything is now easier and possible.

```
// styles.xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<-------------->
// Manifest.xml
<activity
    android:name="com.example.MyExample.activity_B"
    android:label="@string/activity_B"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" 
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
</activity>
```

And then I can use in my custom adapter:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), activity_B.class);
i.putExtra("field", "value");
context.startActivity(i);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try This-

```
String title1 = this is the title;
Intent i = new Intent(context, activityB.class);
i.putExtra("title", title1);
```

Then extract it from your new activity-

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String title1 = intent.getExtras.getString("title");
```